# Neatly get query string with comma separated values

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string, str-replace

I'm trying to get a query string that looks like:

```
?focuses=coding,robotics,electronics&format=clp,hlp
// or this
?focuses=coding,robotics,electronics
// or this
?focuses=coding&format=clp
```

I have been working on this:

```
// formats = ['hlp', 'clp'], focuses = ['coding', 'robotics']
var query = jQuery.param({formats, focuses});
query = query.replace(/%5B%5D/g, '');
query = query.replace(/(?!^)&formats=/g, ',');
query = query.replace(/(?!^)$focuses=/g, ',');
```

But I somehow keep ending up with:

```
?formats=hlp,clp,coding,robotics,electronics
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A custom function would be:

```
 function query(args){
   return "?" + Object.entries(args).map(([key, value]) => {
     return key +"="+ value;
  }).join("&");
}
```

So one can do:

```
 query({
  focuses:["what", "ever"],
  a:"property"
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Get your objects into the form you want before passing them off to jQuery:

```
jQuery.param({
  formats: formats.join(','),
  focuses: focuses.join(',')
});
```

This still encodes the commas as `%2C` (which is valid), but if you really want to use literal commas, you can replace them afterward:

```
jQuery.param({
  formats: formats.join(','),
  focuses: focuses.join(',')
}).replace(/%2C/g, ',');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this way. If you do not require a reusable function `getQueryString` then you can move that code outside of that function where you need.

```js
var formats = ['hlp', 'clp'], focuses = ['coding', 'robotics','electronics'];

function getQueryString(formats, focuses){
  var formatsString = formats.toString();
  var focusesString = focuses.toString();
  var finalString = "?focuses="+focusesString+"&format="+formatsString;
  return finalString;
}

var result = getQueryString(formats, focuses);
console.log(result);
```